# Media queries for every 250px interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'm just wondering if there's a more sophisticated way of achieving the following media queries: jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/XMmyA/ 
CSS:

```
.block {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .block {
        width: 750px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    .block {
        width: 500px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .block {
        width: 250px;
    }
}
```

Thus instead of declaring a different media query every 250px, is there a better way to achieve this with css or jquery? So every 250px, the `.block` width is reduced by 250px. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you've got is the only way in CSS alone - which is the best solution by far as you shouldn't rely on JS for UI.

Comment: As an alternative, you can have PHP (or whatever server-side scripting language you are using) generate the media query CSS for you for as wide as you need your screen to be.

Comment: You can take a look at [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). They might not suit your needs, but they are both CSS pre-processors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the css preprocessor [sass](http://sass-lang.com/) for this, along with a [for loop](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while).

```
@for $i in 1 through 3 {
    @media only screen and (max-width: (5-$i) * 250px) {
        .block {
            width: (4-$i) * 250px;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip using media queries, why not just set the width of your block using a percentage ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XMmyA/1/)):

```
.block {
    width: 75%;
    min-width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Presumably the OP wants the width of the block to increase in steps of 250px rather than fluidly.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
$(function() {
var windowsize = parseInt($(window).width());
var block = parseInt($(".block").outerWidth(true));

if(windowsize <= block && windowsize%250==0) {
$(block).css('width',windowsize-250+"px");
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: In my opinion, styles should be set in CSS as far as possible. And it's possible in this case...

Comment: @Anders G: It's not possible without a preprocessor - and with a preprocessor you're just generating static CSS anyway. There is no way to do this dynamically with CSS.